# jQuery mobile radio buttons showing blue in native app using Phonegap

Tags: css, cordova, jquery-mobile, radio-button

I have some radio buttons in my app, using jQuery Mobile 1.1.1. If I open it in a web browser, incluiding Android's native browser, they display ok. There's an screenshot taken from Android's native browser:

[image]

But when I package the app using Phonegap I get buttons look blue:

[image]

Actually, it's not only the radio buttons, they're all the buttons on that page. I've put explicitly `data-theme="c"` to that page (it's the "gray" one). Anyone knows why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this adding `data-theme="c"` to each element instead of the whole page.